# How to exclude local maven repository when installing grape dependencies

Tags: groovy, groovy-grape

I want install some grape depencies to my project:

```
grape install org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder http-builder 0.6
```

How I can exclude downloading from my maven local repository ? Becase by default it looks like it download from my local repo

```
found org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder#http-builder;0.6 in localm2
found org.apache.httpcomponents#httpclient;4.2.1 in localm2
found org.apache.httpcomponents#httpcore;4.2.1 in localm2
found commons-logging#commons-logging;1.1.1 in localm2
found commons-codec#commons-codec;1.6 in localm2
```

...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have your local maven repo in the resolvers section of `grapeConfig.xml` (`~/.groovy/grapeConfig.xml`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ivysettings>
    <settings defaultResolver="downloadGrapes"/>
    <resolvers>
        <chain name="downloadGrapes">
            <!-- todo add 'endorsed groovy extensions' resolver here -->
            <ibiblio name="local" root="file:${user.home}/.m2/repository/" m2compatible="true"/>
            <filesystem name="cachedGrapes">
                <ivy pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/ivy-[revision].xml"/>
                <artifact pattern="${user.home}/.groovy/grapes/[organisation]/[module]/[type]s/[artifact]-[revision].[ext]"/>
            </filesystem>
            <ibiblio name="codehaus" root="http://repository.codehaus.org/" m2compatible="true"/>
            <ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true"/>
            <ibiblio name="java.net2" root="http://download.java.net/maven/2/" m2compatible="true"/>
        </chain>
    </resolvers>
</ivysettings>
```

With the line bellow inside the `resolvers` section, `grape` gets artifacts from the local maven repo:

```
<ibiblio name="local" root="file:${user.home}/.m2/repository/" m2compatible="true"/>
```

Comment it out to download artifacts from the configured repos.

**EDIT**: just tested locally with joda-time

First, with my local maven repo included in grapeConfig.xml

```
> grape install joda-time joda-time 2.1
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/C:/Software/groovy-2.1.1/lib/ivy-2.2.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysettings.xml
:: resolving dependencies :: caller#all-caller;working16
        confs: [default]
        found joda-time#joda-time;2.1 in local
downloading file:C:/Users/jalopaba/.m2/repository/joda-time/joda-time/2.1/joda-time-2.1.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] joda-time#joda-time;2.1!joda-time.jar (90ms)
```

After manually deleting `joda-time` folder in `~/.groovy/grapes` and commenting out the line above:

```
> grape install joda-time joda-time 2.1
:: loading settings :: url = jar:file:/C:/Software/groovy-2.1.1/lib/ivy-2.2.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/core/settings/ivysetti    ngs.xml
:: resolving dependencies :: caller#all-caller;working09
        confs: [default]
        found joda-time#joda-time;2.1 in ibiblio
downloading http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/joda-time/joda-time/2.1/joda-time-2.1.jar ...
        [SUCCESSFUL ] joda-time#joda-time;2.1!joda-time.jar (2460ms)
```

**EDIT 2**: edited following my comment below:

If you can't create the `grapeConfig.xml` in `~/.groovy` but you can create it in other path, you can do

```
grape -Dgrape.config=<pathTo_grapeConfig.xml> install joda-time joda-time 2.1
```

Comment: I dont have any grapeConfig.xml and by default it downloading from local repo. When I created one and I dont add local repo then it is downloading from internet problem is in my case I cant create this config

Comment: If you can't create the grapeConfig.xml in ~/.groovy but you can create it in other path, you can do grape -Dgrape.config=<pathTo_grapeConfig.xml> install etc.