# GrabResolver can only add repositories - how to remove them?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, nexus

With the GrabResolver in Groovy/Jenkins (http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.10/html/api/groovy/lang/GrabResolver.html), you can add additional repositories to the resolution chain. I would like to *remove* all standard repositories (as MavenCentral), but I did not find a way.

The reason: Those repositories are not available inside our company, and contacting them until timeout wastes a huge amount of time in the process.

Comment: Is it possible by [altering the Ivy Resolver](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html#Grape-CustomizeIvysettings) on each machine in your jenkins setup?

Comment: @tim_yates If I write such a settings file, MavenCentral is still contacted (jcenter is dropped, though). Can I tell Ivy _not_ to contact repo1.maven.... ?

Comment: Your file looks like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15784791/how-to-exclude-local-maven-repository-when-installing-grape-dependencies yeah?

Comment: More or less. I just found out that I probably have to eliminate the line `<ibiblio name="ibiblio" m2compatible="true"/> `

Comment: What about forwarding those domains to `127.0.0.1` via `/etc/hosts` so it can fail very fast?